# How to run multiple coroutines in Kotlin in parallel without waiting for result?

Tags: spring, kotlin

I have a service, which send messages to multiple users. I calling send method in for-each cycle and I want to parallel this operations without waiting a result. I've wrote some code, but i need your comment if i implemented it correctly. Use Kotlin + Spring 5.

Service A (singleton service):

```
fun send(users: List<User>) {
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
        users.forEach {
            launch(SupervisorJob() + MDCContext()) {
                val messageText = "Hello, my friend!"
                chatMessageSender.send(it, messageText)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

chatMessageSender - external service, called via RestTemplate

Kotlin playground: [Click here](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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)

Comment: You don't need to add a SupervisorJob to every child coroutine. It serves no purpose if it isn't being used to launch its own children. Did you mean to put that in the top level CoroutineScope?

Comment: I try to add this to parent coroutine, but when first coroutine occurred an error, other coroutines also not executed. Here is Kotlin Playground https://play.kotlinlang.org/#eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS43LjIwIiwicGxhdGZvcm0iOiJqYXZhIiwiYXJncy[…]AgICB9XG4gICAgcHJpbnRsbihcIm1haW4gZmluaXNoZWRcIilcbn0ifQ==

Comment: Your link is broken.

Comment: Just click on play.kotlinlang.org/... and it will redirect you

Comment: It links to a blank playground. You’re seeing your entered code only because Playground remembers your last code you personally entered.

Comment: Sorry, updated the post and added a link and you're right, I don't need to add a SupervisorJob to every child coroutine. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I launch a coroutine in Kotlin and do not wait for its completion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77403804/how-can-i-launch-a-coroutine-in-kotlin-and-do-not-wait-for-its-completion)

Answer (score 1):

l just want to point a couple of parts of your codes.

1- If you want to handle exceptions during sending message you can use try catch in launch block like that.

```
launch(SupervisorJob() + MDCContext()) {
                try{
                val messageText = "Hello, my friend!"
                chatMessageSender.send(it, messageText)
                }catch(e: Throwable){
                  //message could not be sent to it user 
                   }
  
            }
```

2-`launch(SupervisorJob() + MDCContext())`  Do you really need MDCContext here? l guess you are not using it.

3- Maybe you can consider about using Dispatchers.IO instead of Dispatchers.Default. You can find comparison of this two in here
https://medium.com/@bhavnathacker14/deep-dive-into-dispatchers-for-kotlin-coroutines-f38527bde94c

Comment: MDCContext used for logging thread local variables in chatMessageSender. Thank you for detailed review 