# How can I launch a coroutine in Kotlin and do not wait for its completion?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I want to run a job in "fire and forget" manner with help of Kotlin coroutines.
It means that I want to spawn a process and not interested in its completion.
I found out that I can do

```
    GlobalScope.launch {
        ...
    }
```

At the same time usage of `GlobalScope` is discouraged in [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-global-scope/).
Is there any best practice how to do that?
Something simple like

```
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> { ... });
```

or

```
executorService.submit(() -> { ... });
```

Comment: With `executorService.submit()` you still have to take care to shut down the`executorService`. This is pretty much exactly the same as creating a `CoroutineScope` object and cancelling it at that point.

Answer (score 4):

The reason GlobalScope is discouraged is that usually you care about the scope of long running actions and want an easy way to cancel work when it goes out of the scope of what you're doing in the app, so you're not wasting resources and memory.

If you have a task that you want to be able to fire and forget, with no situation where you would need to cancel it automatically along with other similar tasks you've started, then GlobalScope is appropriate. Even if you do want to cancel it under a certain circumstance, you can still do that if you keep the reference to the Job returned by `launch` and cancel that.

This is normally a rare situation, and so GlobalScope is discouraged for that reason. Usually, you have scopes of your app. For example, in an app with a UI, you have a screen where you want to load and show some data. You would want all work related to those tasks to be canceled when the user navigates away from that screen, so GlobalScope would not be appropriate. Instead, you would have your own CoroutineScope associated with that screen that you cancel when the screen is closed. For example, on Android, this scope is already provided for you and already set up to cancel itself at the appropriate event--it's called `lifecycleScope`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use async block for Job. It returns Deferred which is a Job with a result. But the point is that you do not need to wait for its completion. For the below example it prints "kotlinx.coroutines.DeferredCoroutine" first without any delay then it prints "false" 3 seconds later. Because it waits for it.

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val job1 = GlobalScope.async { longJob1() }
    val job2 = GlobalScope.async { longJob2() }
    println(job1)
    println(job2)
    println("Run without concerning yourself with whether the jobs are done.")
}

suspend fun longJob1(): Boolean {
    println("longJob1 has started")
    delay(3000)
    return true
}

suspend fun longJob2(): Boolean {
    println("longJob2 has started")
    delay(3000)
    return false
}
```

The result is in below. It doesn't wait for 3 seconds to print last message

```
DeferredCoroutine{Active}@7b49cea0
DeferredCoroutine{Active}@887af79
Run without concerning yourself with whether the jobs are done.
longJob1 has started
longJob2 has started
```

Comment: This is waiting for completion of both jobs because of the use of `coroutineScope { }`. OP's question is about how to use a proper scope for launching a job that you don't want to wait for. The `main` function can't really be used to show an example of this, since it represents the entire lifetime of the app, and must wait for even "fire and forget" coroutines to avoid cancelling them.

Comment: Thanks @Tenfour04. Yes you are right I didn't think in that way. Also usage inside of main is just an example I thought it can be used in your own coroutine scope. And I updated the code do you have any feedback?

Comment: Well, since you’re still using `main` but now you’re not waiting for the coroutines, they will be terminated immediately. The OP probably wants to launch coroutines somewhere lower in their application and just doesn’t want to wait for them inside the method that executes them.